# PHP Remove Hard Return From Output

Tags: php, string, replace

I realize there are some post on this subject. I have looked at them and tried the code but it is not working for my particular code. Could someone please help me with the code that will remove returns from the out put. Here is my code.

```
function random_phrase () 
{ 
$quotes = file ("quotes.txt");
$num = rand (0, intval (count ($quotes) / 3)) * 3;
return $quotes[$num];
}
```

To call it I am using `random_phrase()`

Tried both of these:

```
str_replace("\n", "")

str_replace(array("\r","\n"))
```

Maybe I didn't have them in the right place though.

My out put is looking like this:

```
Quote 1
Quote 2
Quote 3
```

I'm wanting:

```
Quote 1 Quote 2 Quote 3
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't tell us what you have tried and why that didn't work for you making any answers just guesswork.

Comment: Also: what do you mean by "code that will remove returns from the output"? Ah, now I see: you mean "linebreaks"!

Comment: So to make it clear, you just want to remove all new line characters in your return statement?

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Have you actually considered [RTFMing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) the [functions](http://php.net/str_replace) you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all new line characters in your return statement this should work for you:

(Here i simply used [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php))

```
return strtr($quotes[$num], array(PHP_EOL => " "));
```

Or even simpler if you want you can change your [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) call and do it like this:

```
$quotes = file("config.php", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Thank you Rizier123. Your second suggestion did work on my server and my returns are now removed on the final WordPress out put. Much appreciated.